# Unambiguous grammar with two different parsing tree

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, ambiguity

our teacher asked to give a unambiguous grammar and two different parsing tree for the same string .
as far as i know only ambiguous grammar can have more than one
can you guys explain for me or give me an example

Comment: Did your teacher ask for two different parse trees? Or, perhaps more likely, did your teacher ask for two different derivations of the same string in the language? The latter is possible for unambiguous grammars, e.g., leftmost vs rightmost derivations.

Comment: For example, in C++ `a * b;` can both represent a declaration of a variable of a type `a*`, if `a` is a type, or an expression `mul(var(a), var(b))` if `a` is an identifier.